# ggplot - How to stack and group bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have two bar charts with the same factor labels that I'd like to combine into one graph ([lines 59-62](https://github.com/BCBugajski/Master-of-Science-in-Data-Science/blob/b92a2a21194885b637dec77b6bd38f8a60b63b3a/NYPD%20shootings.Rmd)) so that for each age group, there are two bars (one for perpetrator age and one for victim age) and each bar retains the stacked murdered/not murdered bar.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include your code and sample data in the text of the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is kind of impossible, because the bars should be stacked by two variables. There is for sure a way to do what you want, but the easiest way in my opinion is to `reshape2::melt` your data.frame and then facet side by side the two graphs.

```
m <- reshape2::melt(shootings[,c(2,5,8,9)],measure.vars=c("Perp_Age","Victim_Age"))

ggplot(m, aes(fill=Murdered, y=Cases, x=value))+
  geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity')+
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

wich gives you this plot:

[image]

Comment: This is still better than what I had before. Thank you!